# Folder - files monitor alert

Tags: windows, directory, monitoring

I would like to monitor one network folder and get some alert/email when new file will be saved in it. Has anyone know any script for it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

One of the option is to use Powershell to monitor folders.

Other options are using Task scheduler to run scripts like .bat to check for new files.

Below is a good reference for your question :

https://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created